# iphone application

Tags: iphone

i want to display an output of html text file in iphone using xcode?
how to run and get output of html file

Comment: Please edit your topic title to be meaningful and put some more effort into your question. That will dramatically increase the likelihood of getting useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIWebView should makes just what you need.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];    
    UIWebView* wv = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 200)];
    [wv loadHTMLString:@"<html><body>Hello <b>World</b></body></html>" baseURL:nil];
    [window addSubview:wv];
    [wv release];             
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UIWebview to show your html.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Wolvorin, see the accepted answer. The only difference is that the accepted answer has sample code and my message dont have it. I think you didn't understand the answer provided by me.

Comment: Hi I understand it but as my comment suggest have to post it as comment first and if OP want it as answer then post it as answer.

Comment: @Wolvorin How can it be a comment. Its the answer to the question "how to show html file". And so its the answer that I provided. Better understand what's the difference between comment and answer.